# How do I print a syntax-highlighted LaTeX source file?

Tags: syntax, printing

I want to print an example source file so that I can study it. How do I print it with syntax highlighting? I'm currently using TeXShop in MacTeX; apparently it doesn't have this ability. What program do you recommend to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try including the code inside another document using the [minted](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) package -- I don't think the listings package does colored syntax highlighting by default, but minted does.

Comment: `minted` and [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) really do their job well :)

Answer (score 10):

How about typesetting the source using the `listings` package and then printing the resultant pdf?

Comment: This seems a little roundabout: put the whole source inside a `listings` environment in another tex file and compile that. Surely there's an easier way to just print the plaintext, suitably coloured...

Comment: @Seamus: well you can use `\lstinputlisting` so you don’t need to do any copy&paste acrobatics. That’s not all that roundabout.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that

Answer (score 5):

Emacs with auctex.

`M-x ps-print-buffer-with-faces`

Actually it will work without auctex too, but that would be silly.

Comment: Or from gvim or gedit (probably not available on mac) or many other good text editors.

Answer (score 0):

gedit with the latex plugin. gedit with latex plugin and embedded terminal I prefer over all of the latex IDEs. Highlight printing should be default.

Comment: AFAIK, gedit doesn't need a plugin to highlight latex.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Highlight Code Converter](http://www.andre-simon.de/zip/download.html)
Produces highlighted code for a ton of languages, plus you can always write your own syntax file if the language you want isn't include. Free (under GPL3), available for most flavors of Linux, Windows, and Mac. Outputs in HTML, XHTML, TeX, LaTeX, RTF, XML, and SVG. Colors are easily customized.