# How to print any command on the PDF document exactly like in the TeX file?

Tags: verbatim

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 My text.
\end{document}
```

Here 'My text' is the output.But I want to get the following output:

```
\begin{document} 
My text 
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to get this output ?

Comment: Here 'My text' is the output.But I want to get the following output: '\begin{document} My text \end{document}'. Is there any way to get this output ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Are you asking about the `verbatim` environment?

Comment: Related/Duplicate: [How do I print a syntax-highlighted LaTeX source file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4440)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Use the `verbatim` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{document}
 My text.
\end{document}
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

If you want to output the whole source code of some file, say myfile.tex, you can make a frame file and use `\VerbatimInput` from the `fancyvrb` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\VerbatimInput{myfile.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: with `\usepackage{verbatim}`, `\verbatiminput{myfile.tex}` (lowercase `\verbatiminput`) does the same thing.  if you want a file to input itself, you can say `\verbatiminput{\jobname.tex}`.  (great for documenting small examples.)